# Creating 2d Matrix from dataframe entries

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe

I have a 2d pandas dataframe with several columns. I want to create a 2d matrix with the count of the number of items in each group for the two columns `C` and `Hr`.

After applying the function
    `df.groupby(['C', 'Hr']).count()`

I obtained the following dataframe:

```
C   Hr  A   B   C   D                       
US  22  2   2   2   2
    1   3   3   3   3
JP 14   2   2   2   2
   19   4   4   4   4
   20   2   2   2   2
```

How am I able to obtain a 2d matrix/dataframe with C and Hr on each of the axis instead? There is no need to retain the any other columns names, just the count which is the same for all columns.

Example output:

```
Hr  US  JP ...
1   2   3  ...
2   3   1  ...
3   3   4  ...
```

Or with the axis flipped works as well

Comment: Can you add sample of your data and desired output? And in sample are two columns `C`?

Comment: @jezrael Hope you understand what I mean, the solution provided does not produce the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with aggregating `len` and if you need fill `NaN` to `0` use parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
print df.pivot_table(index='Hr', columns='C', values='A',  aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Hr': [1] * 10 + [2] * 6 + [3] * 4,
                   'A': np.arange(20),
                   'C': ['US'] * 10 + ['JP'] * 10 })

print df
     A   C  Hr
0    0  US   1
1    1  US   1
2    2  US   1
3    3  US   1
4    4  US   1
5    5  US   1
6    6  US   1
7    7  US   1
8    8  US   1
9    9  US   1
10  10  JP   2
11  11  JP   2
12  12  JP   2
13  13  JP   2
14  14  JP   2
15  15  JP   2
16  16  JP   3
17  17  JP   3
18  18  JP   3
19  19  JP   3

print df.pivot_table(index='Hr', columns='C', values='A',  aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
C   JP  US
Hr        
1    0  10
2    6   0
3    4   0
```

If you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and remove columns names, use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print df.pivot_table(index='Hr', columns='C', values='A',  aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

   Hr  JP  US
0   1   0  10
1   2   6   0
2   3   4   0
```

Comment: The entries are correct, but how do I flip the countries column onto the horizontal axis, as in the example output